# python [regex] - search function is not working while reading lines from a file

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have written the following python section code in order to open a file and read it line by line and detect if a line is starting by a letter or number.

For some strange reason, the `search()` function is not working correct as a result we never enters the `if` statement. My code is below:

```
import re

path = "path/to/my/file/data.txt" 

with open(path, 'r') as f:
    line = f.read()
    if (re.search("^[a-zA-Z0-9]", line)):
        print "YES"
```

Comment: Your question is tagged as "python-3.x", but you use the python-2.x exclusive `print`- statement without parentheses. You might have made a typo in one of those

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To iterate over the file line by line

```
import re

path = "path/to/my/file/data.txt" 

with open(path, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:       # iterating over the file object line by line
        if (re.search("^[a-zA-Z0-9]", line)):
            print "YES"
```

Comment: Working perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read the file line by line, you need to iterate over it, like this, `f.read()` will just load  the entire file as a string, so your `if` will only be reached once for all data. If it doesn't start with an alphanumerical, you won't reach your `print`.

To iterate over it, you can do that with

```
with open(path, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if (re.search("^[a-zA-Z0-9]", line)):
            print("YES")
```